# Перевод кода из Pascal в C#

Tags: c#, pascal

```
program Quantity;
const N=10; .
type Mas=array [1..N] of integer; 
var a: Mas;
i: integer; 
S: integer; 
begin
randomize; 
for i:=1 to N do 
begin
a[i]:=-100+random(201); 
write(a[i]:5) 
end;
writeln; 
S:=0; 
for i:=l to N do
if A[i]>50 then 
S:=S+1; 
writeln('Количество элементов больше 50=',S); 
readln 
end.
```

Comment: @Алексей Скляр, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор не прилагает ни малейших усилий по самостоятельному решению проблемы.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

А что именно не ясно?

**randomize** инициализация генератора случайных чисел

**for** Цикл

**random** генератор случайных чисел

**write** вывести в консоль

**if... then** условие

**type Mas=array [1..N] of integer;** определили массив